# reCAPTCHA falha no file_get_contents

Tags: php, recaptcha

Estou tentando incrementar um reCAPTCHA em um site, já assisti vários passo a passo, mas o meu persiste em dar o mesmo erro. código exemplo:

```
index.php
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">
    <head>
        <title>index</title>
        <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <form method="post" action="verify.php">
             <input type="text" name="inp"/></br>
             <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="********************"></div>
             <input type="submit"></br>
         </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

verify.php

```
<?php
header("Content-type: text/php charset=utf-8");
if(isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])&& $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']){
     var_dump($_POST);
     //informações sobre o reCAPTCHA
     $secret = "**************************************************";
     var_dump($secret);
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     var_dump($_SERVER);
     $captcha =  $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
     var_dump($captcha);
     //Enviar para o google
     $rps = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip$ip");
     //resposta google
     var_dump($rps);
    // $arr = json_decode($rsp,true)
  }else{
     echo "reCAPTCHA não prenchido";
}
```

O erro sempre ocorre no

```
 $rps = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip$ip");
```

O `var_dump($rps);` deveria retornar `"success": true` mas sempre retorna

> **Warning**:  file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: URL
>   file-access is disabled in the server configuration in
>   **/home/storage/2/8a/81/necon1/public_html/verify.php** on line
>   **13**

Comment: Veja no PHP.ini, se tiver acesso, o parâmetro `allow_url_fopen` ou utilize CURL como mencionado nas respostas.

Answer (score -1):

Alguns servidores desabilitam o uso de file_get_contents, em outras palavras, o google bloqueou qualquer acesso proveniente de file_get_contents. Você pode utilizar o cURL do PHP para driblar o bloqueio. No caso, seu código ficaria assim:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$captcha&remoteip$ip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);


$rps = curl_exec($ch);

//print da resposta do google
echo "<pre>"
print_r($rps);

curl_close($ch);
```

[Clique aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php) para acessar o manual cURL.

Comment: Não foi o Google quem bloqueou, foi ele mesmo no PHP.ini, usando `allow_url_fopen = Off`, provavelmente.

Comment: Estou com o mesmo erro e a diretiva allow_url_fopen está habilitada no php. O que vocês sugerem ?